Random hardware address is on, How to get the real mac address of windows system
This issue is not repeated, please turn it on!!!
Windows 10 and windows 11 have a random hardware address feature, when this feature is turned on, the network card gets a random mac address for privacy purposes every time a new WIFI is accessed. Is there a way to get the real mac address when the random hardware address is turned on.
I have developed a windows application, and previously I have been able to differentiate between clients by getting the mac address.
But recently I realized that when windows random hardware address is on, it causes me to not get the real mac address, which causes me to not be able to uniquely differentiate between clients. Is there any way to bypass the random hardware address to get the real mac address
I've tried reading the registry, and using c++ with different permissions, and all I get is the hardware address after randomization
The mac address is used multiple times in my software and it's not too easy to change the mac address to uuid

GetAdaptersInfo

Why not let your client generate a UUID (at install time), persist that (in a file) and reuse that.  Because the client might have had a hardware problem and have its network card changed.

This is a historical problem because I use mac addresses as unique identifiers in many places in my program

Windows Random Hardware feature is specifically designed to stop this sort of tracking (it's illegal in some/many countries without explicit user consent).  You will have to find another approach.

@xiaoguolu you will probably want to clarify that you’re trying to get the real MAC address of the local machine - not of other machines on the WiFi network. The latter is impossible by design; the former should be doable (even if unadvisable) because Windows must have that information somewhere.

Each Ethernet-compatible adapter on the machine will have its own MAC address, so a computer might have zero MAC addresses, or (more commonly) multiple MAC addresses, and these MAC addresses could change from time to time as the user swaps out hardware.  Given all that, using a MAC address as a client identifier isn't all that great of an idea.

@nneonneo Yes, I'm trying to get the local mac address, but I've tried the system interface and the registry, and I'm still getting the windows randomly generated mac address.
